# store data into two tables at time using laravel8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm trying to store data into a database and I encountered a situation where I don't know is it feasible or not to do that.

so I have two following tables in the database

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('castings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_casting');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->string('prenom');
            $table->string('cine');
            $table->date('date_naissance');
            $table->string('lieu_naissance');
            $table->integer('mineur')->default('0');
            $table->integer('id_representant')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('id_representant')->references('id_representant')->on('representants');
        });
    }
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('representants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->increments('id_representant');
            $table->string('nom_prenom');
            $table->string('cine');
            $table->string('lien_casting');
            $table->integer('actif');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My models :

```
class Casting  Model
{
    use HasFactory;
   
extends     protected $fillable = ["id_casting",
        "nom", "prenom" , "cine" , "date_naissance","lieu_naissance" ,"mineur"
    ];


    public function representants()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Representant');
}

}
```

And Model Representant

```
class Representant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     protected $fillable = ["id_representant",
            "nom_prenom", "cine" , "lien_casting","actif"
    ];


    function castings() {

    return $this->hasMany('Casting');
}

}
```

And I have the following form :

```
<form id="castingform" method="post" action="castingss"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
       
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id" />
                        <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_name">Nom</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" >
                             
                           </div> 
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_name">Prénom</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Prenom" >
                         
                           </div>
                           </div>
                         <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_cin">CIN</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cine" name="cine" placeholder="Cin">
                           </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-row">
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_date_naissancee">Date de naissance</label>
                             <div class="input-group date">

                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_naissance" name="date_naissance">
                                            <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                                                <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                                            </span> 
                                        </div>
                                 </div>
                           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="casting_lieu_naissance">Lieu de naissance</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lieu_naissance" name="lien_naissance" placeholder="Lieu de naissance">
                           </div>
                         </div>  
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor-container" hidden>
                        <label for="guarantor">Nom et prénom du représentatnt légal </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom_prenom" name="nom_prenom" placeholder="Représentant">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_identification_number-container" hidden>
                        <label for="guarantor_identification_number">CIN du représentatnt légal</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cine_representant" name="cine_representant" placeholder="CINE">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_lien-container" hidden>
                        <label for="guarantor_identification_number">Lien</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lien_casting" name="lien_casting" placeholder="Lien">
                    </div>      
                       
                    
                        <div class="form-group" align="center">
                          <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
                          <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="ADD" />
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-md-6">
                          <span id="form_result"></span>
                        </div>
                     </form>
```

My script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#date_naissance').change(function (evt) {
 
          var dateinput = $('#date_naissance').val();
         /* alert(dateinput);*/
          var guarantorContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor-container');
          var guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor_identification_number-container');
          var guarantorLienContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor_lien-container');
              var a=  moment().diff(moment(evt.target.value, "MM/DD/YYYY"), 'years');
         /* alert(a);*/
          if (a < 18) {
          guarantorContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
          guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
          guarantorLienContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
          } else {
          guarantorContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
          guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
          guarantorLienContainer.setAttribute('hidden',true);
          }

    });
    });

</script>
```

I managed to insert the data into a single table, but I found the complexity at this level:

It is that at the time of the insertion in my form when I calculate the age from the date of birth and I find that the age is less than 18 years I must insert in the `castings` table the id of the representant and insert it in the table `representans` the information name of the representative, cine of the representative and the link, and all at the same time.
And also if the age is less than 18 the column `mineur` must be set to 1

So I'm trying the following code in my Controller :

```
 public function store(Request $request)

{

      $representants = new Representant();
      $castings = new Casting();
  
      $date = $request['date_naissance']; // 24/8/1995
      $age = Carbon::now()->format('Y')- Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/YYYY', $date)->format('Y');

      if ($age < 18) {

             $representants->nom_prenom = $request['nom_prenom'];
             $representants->cine = $request['cine_representant'];
             $representants->lien_casting = $request['lien_casting'];
             $representants->save();
             $castings->nom = $request['nom'];
             $castings->prenom = $request['prenom'];
             $castings->cine = $request['cine'];
             $castings->date_naissance = $date  ;
             $castings->lieu_naissance = $request['lieu_naissance'];
             $castings->mineur = 1;
             $castings->id_representant = $representants->id_representant;
             $castings->save();
  }else{
     
             $castings->nom = $request['nom'];
             $castings->prenom = $request['prenom'];
             $castings->cine = $request['cine'];
             $castings->date_naissance =  $date  ;
             $castings->lieu_naissance = $request['lieu_naissance'];

  }
    }
```

But I get the following error :

{message: "Unexpected data found. ↵Data missing",…}
exception: "Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException"
file: "D:\Projet_Cast_Infl\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php"
line: 643
message: "Unexpected data found.\r\nData missing"

If you have any idea help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$age = Carbon::parse($date)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
```

Comment: thank for ur help , that works for my problem , but Now I get the following error , message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'id_representant' ne peut être vide (null) (SQL: insert into `castings` (`nom`, `prenom`, `cine`, `date_naissance`, `lieu_naissance`, `mineur`, `id_representant`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (BOUALAMIA, Hajar, 125mjj, 2018-06-26, CASA, 1, ?, 2021-06-12 19:12:38, 2021-06-12 19:12:38))"

Comment: it doesn't insert the id of the second table representant

Comment: Can you show me your representant migration? Also i think you should insert $representant->id not $representant->id_representant

Comment: check the question , I already put the representant migration

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in Carbon method, not in model, check the data passed to

```
$age = Carbon::now()->format('Y')- Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/YYYY', $date)->format('Y');
```

$date mayebe the problem

Comment: thak you for ur help , please how can I check the value of $date ?

Comment: just dd($date) and it will be returned to the browser

Comment: I get "06/26/2018"

Comment: so its mm/dd/YYYY, not dd/mm/YYYY